# Extracting the standard error map from autoKrige in R

Tags: r, kriging

autoKrige in R works fine and plotting the output gives a good overview of the interpolation with standard error. Following these steps:

```
library(sp)
library(automap)

loadMeuse()
demo(meuse)
# Ordinary kriging
kr = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid)
plot(kr)

#Extracting parts from the autoKrige object
prediction_spdf = kr$krige_output
sample_variogram = kr$exp_var
variogram_model = kr$var_model
plot(prediction_spdf)
```

In the last line I only plot the extracted prediction. I also want a separate standard error plot, but I can't extract that from the autoKrige output. Anyone who knows how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `krige_output` component of `kr` is a SpatialPixelsDataFrame. Plotting it only shows the first component. The components are:

```
> names(kr$krige_output)
[1] "var1.pred"  "var1.var"   "var1.stdev"
```

So to get the kriging variance you do:

```
> plot(kr$krige_output[,"var1.var"])
```

You can also use `spplot`, eg for the std deviation:

```
> spplot(kr$krige_output,"var1.stdev")
```